# Is $ \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ an $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be a left $R$-module,then I have to show that $ \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M) \cong M$. But for that I will have to make $ \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ an $R$-module. I tried $r.\alpha(s)=\alpha(rs)$ as well $r.\alpha(s)=\alpha(sr)$, where $r,s\in R$ and $\alpha \in  \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$. But the former didn't qualify for third module axiom and latter didn't make $r.\alpha$ an $R$-linear map.

I know it will be an $R$-module if $R$ is commutative, but it isn't given commutative in the question. Is there an error in question or am I missing something?

Comment: Does it work to define $r \cdot \alpha$ by $(r \cdot \alpha)(s) = r \cdot (\alpha(s))$?

Comment: Why do you say that with your second definition $r.\alpha$ is not a $R$-linear map ? It is obviously additive and $(r.\alpha)(sx)=\alpha(sxr)=s\alpha(xr)=s((r.\alpha)(x))$. This is actually the good definition.

Comment: @AlexZorn This does not work : $r.\alpha$ is not $R$-linear with this definition : $(r.\alpha)(sx) =r(\alpha(sx))=rs\alpha(x)\neq s((r.\alpha)(x))=sr\alpha(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to make $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)$ into a left $R$-module is to define
$$s\cdot f:r\mapsto f(rs).$$ 
Then
$$s'\cdot(s\cdot f):r\mapsto(s\cdot f)(rs')=f(rs's)=((s's)\cdot f)(r)$$
etc.

But the elements of $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)$ all have the form $f_m:r\mapsto rm$
where $m\in M$, and then $m\mapsto f_m$ is the required isomorphism. We check:
$$s\cdot f_m:r\mapsto f_m(rs)=rs m=f_{sm}(r).$$